# Antlr MissingTokenException with simple grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, lexer

I have what I would think would be the world's simplest grammar, parsing file system paths of the form dir1/dir2/filename (without a leading /).  I've cut out some detail to get a small sample exhibiting the problem.

```
compilationUnit : relativePath;
identifier: IdentifierStart IdentifierPart*;    
relativePath : identifier (SLASH identifier)*;

SLASH   :   '/';
fragment IdentifierPart : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9';
fragment IdentifierStart :  'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_';
```

if I feed it something like foo/aa/bb, I get a MissingTokenException.  It identifies an identifier, then gets the SLASH, and I get a MissingTokenException hanging off the identifier.  Must be something fundamental I am missing, but what ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put the keyword `fragment` in front of a lexer rule, you cannot use this rule in parser rules. A `fragment` can only be used inside other lexer rules. Such rules never become tokens on their own, they can only be used as part of other tokens (other lexer rules).

In other words: remove these `fragment` keywords from your grammar:

```
// parser rules
compilationUnit : relativePath;
relativePath    : identifier (SLASH identifier)*;
identifier      : IdentifierStart (IdentifierStart | Digit)*;    

// lexer rules
SLASH           : '/';
IdentifierStart : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_';   
Digit           : '0'..'9';
```

However, a relative path could also be made into a single token, in which case you *can* leave the `fragment` keywords but must make some parser rules into lexer rules, like this:

```
// parser rule
compilationUnit : RelativePath;

// lexer rules
RelativePath    : Identifier ('/' Identifier)*;

fragment Identifier      : IdentifierStart IdentifierPart*;
fragment IdentifierPart  : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9';
fragment IdentifierStart : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_';
```

But then there will never be a `Identifier` token created for the parser since a RelativePath matches a single `Identifier`. Therefor, `Identifier` should also be a `fragment`. So perhaps that is not what you want.

Comment: I ended up asking this question on the antlr list.  The explaination provided was that turning identifier into a parser rule by capitalizing it should solve the problem, as the parser would never see the fragments IdenifierStart and IdentifierEnd.  Running the rule in the lexer solved the problem.

Comment: @seven-seven, I don't understand why you asked there: I already gave the answer, no?